# Permission problems with Drupal directory

Tags: server, ubuntu-16.04, lamp, drupal-8, localserver

I really suck at permissions. I recently installed Drupal on my Ubuntu server and it was working like a charm. Suddenly it got stuck, and I got

> There's no internet connection
>   error on Google Chrome and
>
> Server not found error
>   on Firefox. However my Apache is still working.

My Drupal is located at `/var/www/html/drupal test`. However when I type `cd drupaltest` I got a permission denied error. I changed the permission with:
    sudo chmod 660 drupaltest
After that I could get into that directory, but not any directory inside. I am constantly getting permission denied error. I tried adding the -R option, drupaltest/*, and even giving 770. The owner is my current user on the machine, but I still have no idea why I can't access the subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

Try chown -R owner:group /dirname